# Is the set of decimals of the form $0.x_10x_200x_3000...$ countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider the set of infinite decimal numbers of the form

$$ 0.x_10x_200x_3000... ,$$

where $x_n \in \{1,2,...,9\}$ and the number of zeros after $x_n$ is $n$.

Is the set of such numbers countable? 
A hint would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: welcome to MSE !! Please consider adding in question what attempts you made in the direction of  a solution  of your problem.

Comment: Thanks! I will do that from now on.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* This doesn't look essentially different from the decimal representation of a generic real number.

Comment: Okay, I see your point. So if we just "removed" the zeros, it would be a generic real number... and the zeros doesn't make a difference?

Comment: You are getting point. The quick argument is that you can embed $\{1,2\}^{\Bbb N}$ in that set just like you can embed it in $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

Since, $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ i.e power set of $\mathbb{N}$ is uncountable, hence the set discussed in the question is uncountable. 
http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-set-of-all-subsets-of-natural-numbers-is-uncountable. As inferred by you in other answer, the zeroes don't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, A function $f: [0,1]- \mathbb Q \rightarrow [0,1]$ Sending $0.x_1x_2...$ to $0.x_10x_200x_3...$ is an injection. (I excluded rationals only for not going to the welldefinedness arguments).